# Maven is ignoring resource files when creating the war/jat. How to force it to include them?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am configuring Jenkins (using Maven integration) for the first time. I am liking it but it is not very smooth.
My project has the following structure

```
Repository 1
  -View
  -Model
  -Business

Repository 2
  -Widget library
```

In this widget library, I have the following file tree:

```
  -root
     -src
       -com
         -example
           -file1.java
           -file2.java
           -file3.java
           -widget1.html
           -widget2.html
           -widget3.html
```

My build gets downloaded, compile and a war is generated. It also gets deployed to my remote server and I am very happy about it.
Unfortunately, my project still doesn't open because the widget1.html, widget2.html and widget3.html are missing.
If I unzip my war file and my WidgetLibrary.jar, the .java classes are included there, but the .html are not.

Is there any way to make Maven include all the files in the project?

Comment: Jenkins isn't creating your Jar, your build system (Maven?) is.  All Jenkins is doing (presumably) is invoking Maven.

Comment: The problem is presumably that you're not using the Maven [standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: An unexpected task just poped up. I will take a look in your answer ASAP. Could you please turn you comment into an answer so I can eventually mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is driven by convention, so I would speculate that the problem is you're not using the Maven [standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

In general, your project should look like:

```
    src/
        main/
            java/
                com/example/File.java
            resources/
                file.html
        test/
            java/
                com/example/TestFile.java
            resources/
                testResource.txt
```

This should be invariant of whether it's you or Jenkins building it.